# ArcMap - symbol for one attribute and color for another

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I am new to ArcMap but I got a drawing from the client and looking to add onto the file.  Wondering how you give a specific symbol and color based on info in att table?  I'm not looking to base colors on color ramp but give a specific symbol and color to each item.  I could create a layer for each item but want to do this through classification (as they did it).

When I go into the Layer Properties they seemed to use the Unique Values category (there's info in every one of the 3 Category items).

I can supply more pics as well if needed.  The pic is what they currently have in the dwg and I want to create that for more items.

[image]

Comment: Please add a pic of the symbology set up.  The way unique values works with 3 category items - the categories are fields.  If you have field A, B and C, there will be a symbol for each unique set of ABC.